What is the meaning of "explicit" here?
What does "explicit" mean here?
The second kind of food-place category includes foods that may have originated with a traditional recipe in a particular place, but which over time have become generic food products. New England clam chowder, Black Forest cake, and Yorkshire pudding are examples of such foods. They were once associated with a region, but now are universally known and manufactured without explicit production links to their places of origin other than in their names.
American Heritage Dictionary:

Fully and clearly expressed; leaving nothing implied

Fully developed or formulated

Forthright and unreserved in expression

Readily observable


And does the following example have the same meaning?

I left explicit instructions for the renters on how to clean the pool.


It's a bad word choice.  actual would have been clearer.  "They were once associated with a region but now are universally known and manufactured around the world and those products have no actual link to the original place of origin."

@TimR, actual is certainly a valid word here, but I don't think it's clearer, just different. I compare Yorkshire pudding with Marlborough wine (I'm from NZ). On the wine bottle you will get a marketing blurb selling the benefits of wine from the Marlborough region. The connection between the wine and the place is made explicit. With a Yorkshire pudding you have the name, but nothing else explicitly making that association. The word makes complete sense to me.

@PeterKirkpatrick I would disagree. The word "explicit" applies to statements/utterances about things, not to the things themselves.  It is related to "explicated", that is, it has as its primary meaning "made abundantly clear".   If there is a non-existent production relationship between some pudding made in California, which bears the name Yorkshire Pudding, and Yorkshire England, what is "explicit" about it?  How can something non-existent be "explicit"?

It was an explicit violation of the rule.  That makes no sense. What the speaker means to say is that the act clearly violates a rule that explicitly forbids such action.

And if the pudding is actually made in Yorkshire England, could we say "The pudding is explicitly produced in Yorkshire England"?  The production facilities are explicitly located in Yorkshire England.

In the context of your first example, "explicit" means that the food products mentioned (like New England clam chowder or Black Forest cake) are not produced in a way that clearly or fully links them to their original regions. There's no clear or direct connection to their places of origin in terms of how they are made or where the ingredients come from—just their names.
In your second example, "I left explicit instructions for the renters on how to clean the pool," "explicit" has a similar meaning: the instructions are fully and clearly expressed, leaving nothing vague or implied. You made sure the renters understood exactly how to clean the pool, with no ambiguity.

Thank you.
So definition #4 is the closest, isn't it?

Yes I would say so
